# Is there a way to search documents by trimmed values

Tags: faunadb

I have a collection containing documents of users with contact numbers. For instance a contact number can look like this '082 807 0949' or this '082 8070 949'. I want to fetch user by contact number which is trimmed. Since the match function does a check on exact values, my query returns nothing.

Is there a way I can first trim the document data before I do the search or is there way I can create an index which would trim all the contact numbers for the index.

See code below the query that returns no data:

```
q.Get(
    q.Match(q.Index('guests_by_contact_number'), '0828070949')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReplaceStr($phone, " ", "")` is the ticket. For instance:

```
db> ReplaceStr("082 8070 949", " ", "")
'0828070949'
```

You can combine this with a [binding](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/indexes/bindings.html) to trim the phone number at write time. By making the term over the binding you can search using the normalized phone number.